# Who are our nominees for the moderator positions?

Tags: discussion, moderation

The community's thoughts on moderator nominees are apparently considered by SE for appointing moderators *pro tempore*. [They look for members who:](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).
>
> Bonus points for:
>
> - Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
> - Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
> - Members who have already shown an interest or ability to
>     promote their community.

Nominations:

- should be posted as separate answers.
- can be for yourself.
- should link to the user's meta and main profiles, and perhaps to their Area51 profile and to other activity related to Vi.SE.
- for another user should be edited by that user to confirm their acceptance.

The post linked to above discusses in more detail the process of moderator selection and the powers and responsibilities of moderators *pro tempore*.

Answer (score 32):

[image]
[image]
[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/334455.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/334455)

I would like to nominate [@Carpetsmoker](//vi.stackexchange.com/users/51/carpetsmoker) as my first choice for moderator.

His high reputation makes him an obvious candidate, but that's not my only consideration in making this nomination.  Not only has he been busy earning points on the main site, he has also been highly active in [chat](//chat.stackexchange.com/users/139298/carpetsmoker) and [meta](/users/51/carpetsmoker).

Specifically, I've seen him

- go out of his way to do research to answer a question for me
- help me establish a rational tagging system for the site
- edit questions and answers to improve their quality
- make insightful meta posts
- discuss issues civilly in chat

In my experience, moderators for beta sites need to do a lot more than the minimal exception handling suggested in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).  Good beta moderators also act as leaders, setting the tone for group discussions, lobbying Stack Exchange Community Managers on our behalf, and guiding the community towards graduation.  Everything I have seen so far suggests that @Carpetsmoker cares deeply about the site, and would be an excellent moderator.

I hope that the Community Managers agree, and that @Carpetsmoker accepts my nomination.

---

Thanks :-) **I accept**. Let me very briefly introduce me:

My name is Martin, I'm Dutch, almost 30 years old (yikes), and currently work as a Ruby programmer and part time sysadmin for a small company you've never heard of. I remember I first used Vim on FreeBSD 4.8, so I've been using Vim for *about* 10 years. I now use it as my code editor, word processor, spreadsheet program, and more.

I was very active on the old (now defunct) bsdforums.org since 2006, after that I was involved in founding & then running [daemonforums.org](http://daemonforums.org) for about 5 years, but I'm no longer involved due to shifting interests. I was also a boy scout leader for more than 5 years, and if there's *anything* that can prepare someone for being a moderator then it's 30 children screaming at you ;-)

Comment: Definitely support this nomination. This guy seems to be everywhere: Actively asking and answering on the main site, all over the place in meta and chat, reviewing and editing... +1

Comment: I noticed that Carpetsmoker makes quite a lot of mistakes in English. Is it just quick typing and lack of editing? Or is it lack of language skills, which could potentially lead to misunderstanding? Either way, the first impression is not great.

Comment: @Palec It's not an obstacle, in my opinion. His writing is perfectly understandable, and the value added by his contributions way surpasses any annoyance from minor mistakes. I encourage you to edit away spelling and grammar mistakes that you find on any Stack Exchange post.

Comment: @Palec Yeah, my typing isn't great. Most are just typo's that the spell checker doesn't catch; but I'm sure there are some grammar error and such as well ... My English, as such, is rather good, even if I say so myself. I do my best (in general, not just on this site) ... I wasn't aware it was *that bad* that you see it as a (potential) obstacle, and I'd love it if you could point out some examples for me to learn from...

Comment: I’d like to edit the mistakes away, @200_success, but “Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.”

Comment: Conflict resolution is a very important mod duty. Language mistakes could shift the meaning of what you’re trying to say, or cause others to treat you with less respect, @Carpetsmoker. I’m not saying that it is a major obstacle or that the risk is high, I’m not sure about that as I’ve never been a mod. Just wanted to bring up this topic.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, I noticed the mistakes [here](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/a/135/739). Comprehensible → compressible, indexed → index, accessible to → accessible for, encouraged → encourages, are → arre.

Comment: @Palec Yikes! Thanks! Definitely not my best post :-/

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Thanks for fixing those! :-) BTW I noticed you edited your nomination to introduce yourself. In the first paragraph, there is an extra “tell”, you meant “as my code editor” instead of “a my code editor” and I’m not sure if past simple tense is appropriate in the third paragraph (I’d expect past perfect, maybe I’m wrong). Nitpicking, I know. O:-) I finished.

Comment: I support this nomination. One reason is (please, other candidates, do not to take it personally), he's not an SE moderator so far. I think that the site should have a new face in the moderator team. After all, there will be more than one moderator, so we can get both.

Comment: @Palec Thanks! You're on my "I owe you a beer"-list :-)

Comment: @yo' Actually that was one reason I didn't nominate Gilles. I figured SE wouldn't burden a moderator with so many sites.

Comment: @muru Could the fact that Gilles is an emacs guy possibly have influenced that as well?

Comment: @Caleb no, [he's doesn't seem like the fanboi type](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20056420#20056420). Though his low level of activity did. And I think someone commented here that he would have declined anyway (and then deleted the comment, I think).

Answer (score 23):

[image]
[image]
[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1266491.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1266491)

- Knows his Vi.
- Active on meta
- Moderator at [codegolf.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3808/doorknob) and [puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/39/doorknob)

---

#### Accept

Thanks for the nomination, and I'd be willing to serve as a pro-tem mod for Vi.SE. Not much to say here, but a few points:

- I'm glad that you've claimed I'm active on meta, but I haven't been hashing it out here on meta as much as I'd have liked to (commonly because there's often nothing left unsaid by our other excellent users, but you know, excuses excuses ;) ). (I do have the Convention badge, but most of the nominees here do as well.)
- Others (not here, but on other sites) have previously expressed concern about my age (I just turned 14 a few months ago). I don't think that will be an issue. I've already successfully shown that I am able to moderate other Stack Exchange sites, and age doesn't have to be directly linked to maturity in any case.
- Speaking of which, I'm already a moderator of Programming Puzzles & Code Golf and Puzzling. I do think I'd still have enough time to dedicate to moderate all three sites. PPCG is a relatively stable site with a tightly-knit community, and they're both still in beta, so they don't have as heavy of a workload as a fully graduated site.

Comment: Also, fairly active on the main meta, so he knows the system very well.

Comment: Woah what, I got nominated for mod? I didn't get the memo :P I'll think about it.

Answer (score 19):

[image]
[image]
[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/67314.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/67314)

- Knows his Vi.
- Active on meta (1 of the 3 people to get the [Convention](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/68/convention) badge
- Moderator at [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/1430/josh-petrie)

Comment: THIS GUY. DEFINITELY.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I have the time right now to devote to moderation of another SE site. So I am going to to have to decline.

Answer (score 18):

[image]
[image]
[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/486869.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/486869)

I'd like to nominate [@200_success](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/24/200-success).

I'm too lazy to go into as much detail as he did in his nomination of [@Carpetsmoker](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/51/carpetsmoker), but the effort that he put into that post is actually a great example of why he'd be a good moderator.

I've seen his name popping up all over the main site, and the fact that he actually has [more questions and answers on meta.vi](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/24/200-success) than on the main site suggests that he's very interested in how the site works, as well as in vi/Vim itself, which seems like a good quality for a moderator.

Comment: +1; You beat me to it :-)

Comment: He also has a ton of reputation, respect and experience as a moderator of Code Review. +1; +10 if I could.

Comment: Thanks for the nomination and for all your support. At this point, I think that the community would benefit more if we let some fresh faces develop their moderating talent. The site should be in good hands with Carpetsmoker, Doorknob, and muru.

Answer (score 15):

[image]
[image]
[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1042873.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1042873)

I surprised no one nominated **muru** yet. I think he would make for a fine moderator (I didn't want to add too many nominees last time, and expected
someone else to do it).

Muru was involved in the [Area51 definition](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80441/vi-and-vim?tab=votes&phase=definition#tab-top)
, and has been a useful member of the site since the start of the beta, not just
providing useful answers & questions, but also left many useful comments, made
useful edits to answers & questions, and actively participates in the review
queues.
He doesn't have as many questions/answers on meta as the other candidates,  but
I don't see that as an issue. The posts, comments, and chat show he has an
active interest in building this site.

---

Thanks, Carpetsmoker, I accept the nomination. I have not been a moderator, elected or otherwise anywhere else in SE. I'm a pretty new user, active for less than a year, and haven't even participated in an election yet.

Comment: I would have done it, but he told me he didn't want the position :/ Maybe he'll change his mind! :D

Comment: @Seth I'm not all that certain I'd do a good job, but since the two of you think I have a shot, I accept. :)

Answer (score 9):

[image: vi profile]
[image: meta.vi profile]
[image: network profile]

I don't know if this chap is interested, but I'm nominating him because:

- I keep stumbling across nice answers by him
- He has a nice beard

As an example, I thought this answer of his demonstrates a willingness not only to answer the question, but also to assist the OP with his preconceptions: [function to call shell script with arguments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2406/function-to-call-shell-script-with-arguments#2407)

Another answer with a detailed explanation: [How do I have buffers listed in a quickfix window in Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/how-do-i-have-buffers-listed-in-a-quickfix-window-in-vim/2127#2127)

And this grep trivia: [Is there a way to count the number of occurrences of a word in a file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/93/is-there-a-way-to-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-file/100#100)

Whilst his SE karma is somewhat lower than the others listed here, I hope this nomination will at least serve as a recognition of his efforts!

---

### Accept

Thanks for the nomination! Your comment about my SE karma should help point out that I'm relatively new to being active on SE, but I'm unnaturally passionate about Vim.

So here's a bit about me, I guess. My name is Tom McDonald, and that's the origin of my username. I've heard people pronounce it "tom see-dee-oh", but it's actually "tom mik doh". I'm an avid Vim plugin developer, having authored a few somewhat popular plugins including [exchange.vim](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange) and [lion.vim](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-lion).

Aside from Vim, I'm very passionate about teaching and helping others, so this site is kinda right up my alley.

To be quite honest, I don't know precisely what an SE moderator does, but I'm willing to learn and contribute to the growth and success of this great resource.

Comment: As an FYI, I actually considered nominating @tommcdo before, but his lack of meta activity prevented me from doing so (which I thought was a shame, since I rather liked his answers, comments, and edits)... I don't think this is *that much* of an issue, though ... So +1 ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, regardless, I do feel I should participate more in meta. I'll make an effort to do so :)